# Countifs between two values and input answer in a new sheet with vba

Tags: vba, count

I have Column A with more than 100 Product IDs, Column B with prices. I want to countif Column B is less than 80 and greater than 20, then put the answer into a new sheet. I can't get the counties right. Thank you for helping out!

```
Sub MyCount()
Dim MySum as variant
MySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countifs(B:B,">25", B:B, "<80")
Worksheets.Add.Range("A1").Value = MySum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing correct functions. The following will work. The first and third parameters need range.

```
Sub MyCount()
Dim MySum As Variant
MySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sheet1.Range("B:B"), ">25", sheet1.Range("B:B"), "<80")
Worksheets.Add.Range("A1").Value = MySum
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Countifs(B:B,">25", B:B, "<80") works in Excel. So the worksheetfunction will be different in vba?